# Not much has/have changed

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which of the above is correct?

I am in a dilemma which one is correct. I have an inkling that has is right.

Comment: I've closevoted for lack of prior research (Too Basic), but I could have said it's a duplicate of [“Much of it is” or “Much of it are”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87603/) (also closed for the effectively same reason). Or [Is 'much' always singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220614/) Or [“How much is/are the two fares?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47909/), among others.

Comment: I guess - Not much has changed - sounds better ;)

Comment: [***Much has** changed; **many have** realised*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22much+has+changed+many+have%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) that ***much is*** always singular, but ***many is*** always plural (unless we start bringing the [use–mention distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) :)

Comment: _Much_ is for mass nouns (i.e, it's always singular) and _many_ is for count nouns (always plural). They have special affordances with _not_, but the number doesn't change.